# Adding obstacles programmatically to Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to add a number of random obstacles (boxes in particular) to Gazebo *programmatically*. In particular, given n boxes to add, I'd like to add a box of random dimensions to a random pose (constrained to, say, lie on the ground plane). What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7693/adding-obstacles-programmatically-to-gazebo/) by [Evan Drumwright](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1055/evan-drumwright/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

take a look at [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_world&cat=write_plugin) tutorial, it shows you how to add models to the world from a world plugin.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Evan Drumwright](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1055/evan-drumwright/) on 2014-12-14**:
This is perfect. Thanks!